# How to change "under" toolbar background color?

Tags: java, android, background, android-toolbar

I am trying to implement my custom toolbar to my app. How can i fix problem with background color to make toolbar looks properly? Or mayby i can make this white backgroud transparent. I will be appreciate for any help. If you find this question incorrect or it is not enough information here, please leave a comment.

[image: This is how it looks like]

Here is my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <include layout="@layout/main_toolbar"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_background"/>

    </LinearLayout>


    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/main_menu"/>




</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And toolbar layout:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/mainToolbar"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@drawable/background_shape"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
    app:titleTextColor="@color/colorTextGray"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
    >
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

Here is java code:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.mainToolbar);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
```

[image]
Here what i actually expect.

[image]
This is how i get so far :)

Comment: May I ask what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to make my toolbar without that white background. Problem is that i am using gradient colors so when i try to change toolbar backgroung it just turns into solid "Blue" in that example and it does not looks properly.

Comment: what are you getting if you add @drawable/gradient_background to Linear layout?

Answer (score 5):

You can add your background of FrameLayout to your parent. Then that white colour background will get remove.

```
android:background="@drawable/gradient_background"
```

Add Above code to your DrawerLayout like below example :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_background"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/main_toolbar" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/main_menu" />


</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: It's better but it is still making solid color for background.

Comment: can you add expected UI?

Comment: Try adding it to the <LinearLayout/> holding the toolbar.  The LinearLayout places the toolbar *above* the fragment_container that has a gradient bg. Hence the main content is gradient and the toolbar's behind is still white ( LinearLayout's default color )

Comment: @NadimAnsari I added expected UI

Comment: what are you getting if you add @drawable/gradient_background to Linear layout?

Comment: @NadimAnsari insted of white not fitted to background blue

Comment: and what if you add it to Drawer ? as i asked in answer?

Comment: it seems like it makes separate gradient in toolbar frame. I will screenshot

Comment: I found some kind of solution, thanks to you i knew where should i look